# How to show that the estimator is unbiased and find its variance

Tags: self-study

I am given the following model: $Y_i = \beta X_i + \epsilon_i $ for $i =1,2,3,\dotsc, n$ and I know that $\epsilon_i \sim N(0, \sigma^2 )$ is i.i.d. The question asks me to show that $\widetilde{\beta} = \frac{\bar{Y}}{\bar{X}}$ is unbiased and get its variance.

Hence, given $\mathbf{x} = (X_1, X_2, \dotsc, X_n)^T $:

I calculate $E[\widetilde{\beta} | \mathbf{x}] = E[\frac{\bar{Y}}{\bar{X}} | \mathbf{x} ] = E[\frac{\beta \bar{X} + \epsilon}{\bar{X}} | \mathbf{x} ] = E[\beta | \mathbf{x}] = \beta$ since $E[\epsilon] = 0$.

But then when I try to calculate its variance, $Var[\widetilde{\beta} | \mathbf{x}] = Var[\frac{\bar{Y}}{\bar{X}} | \mathbf{x} ] = \frac{1}{\bar{X}^2} Var[\bar{Y} | \mathbf{x}] = \frac{1}{\bar{X}^2} Var[\beta \bar{X} + \epsilon | \mathbf{x}]$

but this is where I get lost. I believe that then it becomes $\frac{1}{\bar{X}^2} Var[\epsilon | \mathbf{x}] = \frac{\sigma^2}{\bar{X}^2} $.

The correct answer is $\frac{\sigma^2}{n \bar{X}^2}$ but I am not sure where my mistake is located.

Comment: what is $\bar{X}$ and $\bar{Y}$?

Comment: Your notation may be confusing you.  In particular, consider precisely what you intend "$\epsilon$" to mean.

Comment: $\bar{X} = \frac{1}{n} (X_1 + X_2 + \dotsc + X_n)$ and similarly for Y bar.

Comment: I think I get it now! So basically, $\bar{Y} = \frac{\sum Y_i }{n} = \frac{\sum \beta X_i + \epsilon_i}{n}$ and in the end I get $ \frac{1}{\bar{X}^2}Var[\bar{\epsilon} | \mathbf{x}] = \frac{\sigma^2}{n \bar{X}^2}$.

Comment: Yeah, that seems to be correct, thanks!